# Google MAP API - Status code : ERROR

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I built a hybrid application using 3rd party container for iPhone application. We are getting ERROR status code in Production, but we are not able to able to reproduce the ERROR status code in DEV/QA. Can anyone help to find out when Google returns status code as ERROR ? I tried providing wrong address information, without any value, but it always returns some latitude and longitude during my test.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>WOM</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--  Apple metatags -->
     <script>

function loadGoogleScript(clientId) {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.type = 'text/javascript';

 script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=valid_client_id&v=3.21&' +
     'callback=initialize';

 //script.src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false';

 document.body.appendChild(script);
console.log('Google initialization done ');
}

    function initialize() {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
var i;
         var componentRestrictions = { country: 'CA' };
         var count = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 15 ; i++) {

          geocoder.geocode({'address':'Valley Ranch Parkway W, MA','componentRestrictions':componentRestrictions},function(results, status){
         try {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

var lat = ""+results[0].geometry.location.lat();

var long = ""+results[0].geometry.location.lng();

console.log("count = " + count++ + "lat = " + lat + "long = " + long);

}

else{
                    console.log("count = " + count++ + " status = " + status);
                    }
         } catch(e){
        console.log(" exception e " + e);
         }

           });
}

}
    </script>   
</head>

<body onload='loadGoogleScript()'>

    </body>
</html>
```

Status Codes

The "status" field within the Geocoding response object contains the status of the request, and may contain debugging information to help you track down why geocoding is not working. The "status" field may contain the following values:

"OK" indicates that no errors occurred; the address was successfully parsed and at least one geocode was returned.
"ZERO_RESULTS" indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocoder was passed a non-existent address.
"OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" indicates that you are over your quota.
"REQUEST_DENIED" indicates that your request was denied.
"INVALID_REQUEST" generally indicates that the query (address, components or latlng) is missing.
"UNKNOWN_ERROR" indicates that the request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.

Comment: Why -1 vote? Can someone explain?

Comment: `client=valid_client_id` - are you using an actual ID here, not just the 'valid_client_id' placeholder?  Are you sure it's valid for your production URL that you're trying to load this script from?

Comment: I am using the actual id..